# Can't assign data source to the repeater asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, ascx

I'm working on a project and ran into a problem.
For some reason, I can't assign data source to the repeater. I'm using usercontrol

> **SlideshowDemo.ascx**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Slideshow" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>

        <div style="margin:0 auto; width:960px;">
            <div class="slideshowInsideContainer">
                <div class="slideShowText">
                <div style="padding:10px;" class="SlideShowContent">
                    <%= firstText %>
                 </div>
                 </div>
                <img id="SlideShowImage" style="position:absolute; z-index:1; top:0;" src="<%= firstImage %>" />
                <img id="SlideShowImageBG" style="position:absolute; z-index:0; top:0;" src="<%= firstImage %>" />
                <img id="previousBttn" style="position:absolute; z-index:2; top:200px; cursor:pointer; left:0;" src="/images/SlideShow/leftButton.png" />
                <img id="nextBttn" style="position:absolute; z-index:2; top:200px; cursor:pointer; right:0;" src="/images/SlideShow/rightButton.png" />
                 <div class="slideshowItems">
                    <ul>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li class='<%# Container.ItemIndex == 0 ? "selected" : "" %>' id="<%# Container.ItemIndex %>">
            <div class="slideshowtext">
                    <%# Eval("text") %>
                </div>
            <img style="position:absolute; z-index:1; top:0;" src=' <%# Eval("image") %>' />
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
                 </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

> **SlideshowDemo.ascx.cs**

```
public void GetSlideshowData()
    {
        int ID = Convert.ToInt32(slideShowID);
        Node parent = new Node(ID);

        ArrayList repeaterData = new ArrayList();

        Nodes children = parent.Children;

        for (int i = 0; i < children.Count; i++)
        {


            string image = children[i].GetProperty("image").Value.ToString();
            string text = children[i].GetProperty("slideshowText").Value.ToString();

            if (i == 0)
            {
                firstImage = image;
                firstText = text;
            }

            repeaterData.Add(new SlideShowItem(image, text));

        }

        Slideshow.DataSource = repeaterData; //Error: Can't recognize 'Slideshow'
        Slideshow.DataBind();

    }
```

**The problem** is that the `SlideshowDemo.ascx.cs` doesn't recognize `Slideshow`

I get error

> The name 'Slideshow' does not exist in the current context

I also get Warning

> Source file
>   'obj\Debug\TemporaryGeneratedFile_E7A71F73-0F8D-4B9B-B56E-8E70B10BC5D3.cs'
>   specified multiple times

I would appreciate any help

Comment: what do you mean by "doesn't recognize" `Slideshow`? is `Slideshow` `null` once you reach the line where you assign the DataSource, or does this completely fail to compile? a stack trace could be of help.

Comment: I get error "The name 'Slideshow' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: @David, remove current repeater and try to add again may be it's not register in designer file.

Comment: Is `Repeater` named **Slidshow** is inside some kind of container like Panel, Repeater etc

Comment: @Suprabhat - a Panel wouldn't cause issues, but I was going to say the same things - it could be something like a Repeater, GridView, ListView, etc... anything that uses a template setup

Comment: *I get error "The name 'Slideshow' does not exist in the current context"*... the problem is @David, that just telling us there's an error is not enough.  There are two main places that an error can occur... compile time and run time.  You're not helping us by being so vague

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal No, it's not

Comment: @freefaller How can I check if it is compile time or run time error? I'm sorry for being new at this

Comment: Yes, apparently you are - if the error occurs while you're compiling, it's at compile time.  If the error occurs while you're running it, it's at run time

Comment: My guess is compile time - and the most likely thing is that Visual Studio has not added the `Slideshow` control into the designer file.  It's possible that a simple "Save" of the mark-up file (the .ascx) will sort it - otherwise, there could be something within the mark-up file that Visual Studio doesn't like.  If you've added anything recently, backup what you have and then try removing it.  Also check the "Warnings" under the Error List tab to see if VS is complaining that it cannot create the designer file for some reason

Comment: I also get **Warning Source file 'obj\Debug\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_E7A71F73-0F8D-4B9B-B56E-8E70B10BC5D3.cs' specified multiple times**